# How can I load a parquet file line by line

Tags: python, parquet

To save space on my laptop I saved a fairly large dataset as parquet files via dask. And was wondering if there is a way to read in the parquet files line by line.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ParquetFile.iter_row_groups` from the [fastparquet](https://pypi.org/project/fastparquet/) library to iterate over the lines of a parquet file.

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlos, I will give it a try.